# AS400 DDL SQL Syntax for Adding a new column with short and long field name

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, alter

What is the syntax for AS400 SQL DDL to add a column to an existing table?  I also need to specify the long and short field names.

(SQL - Structured Query Language)
(DDL - Data Definition Language:  This is SQL that changes the structure of tables or can modify the settings of the database)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
   ADD long_column_name FOR COLUMN shortname VARCHAR(21)
        BEFORE existing_column_name;
```

You may leave out the BEFORE clause if you are adding the column at the end of the record.

Most IBM i shops would also want column text description and column headings defined.

```
LABEL ON COLUMN mytable.colname    TEXT IS '50 char description goes here';

LABEL ON COLUMN mytable.colname    IS 'Heading Line 1      Heading Line 2      Heading Line 3';
```

Where the column heading string consists of up to 3 section, 20 characters each, allowing the heading to display up to 3 lines high.

The statement defining the column text description is differentiated by using the TEXT keyword.

Comment: That's great!  I'll definitely use the LABEL ON COLUMN from now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD StaffId_Advisor FOR COLUMN Advisor VARCHAR(21)
```

Instead of seeing a field called STAFF00001 in sysibm.SQLColumns you will see Advisor.

Here's a bit of code I use to describe tables:

```
SELECT table_name, system_column_name, column_text, Type_Name, column_Size
FROM sysibm.SQLColumns
WHERE table_schem IN ('UWSP_TEST', 'UWSP_PROD') -- Library Name
AND upper(table_name) like 'STUDENT' -- Table name make sure it is upper case
--order by system_column_name
```

Regarding the field naming convention I used:  StaffId_Advisor
Assume I have a table called Staff.  In this table I have a primary key called StaffId.  The Staff table contains Professors, Assistants, Secretaries, Adjunct Faculty, Student Advisors, Security Guards, etc...  A student might have multiple fields with foreign key constraints with the Staff table.  In order to avoid confusion (and adhere to 1NF in my opinion) I name the field using the Primary Key table's field name followed by the purpose for the field.  This ensures other developers will understand the use of this field.  In addition to single purpose values I contend that 1NF also requires unique naming of fields AND anywhere that field is used the name should be identical.  While this is an implied definition I believe it should be an important distinction.  In this case a modifier is used to clarify the purpose of the field.